# parallel foreach loops produce mclapply error

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Those are my first steps with parallel computing in R. The code below results in the following error. I am clueless, since there is no mclapply function in what I wrote, at least I did not put it explicitly.

Error:

```
Error in mclapply(argsList, FUN, mc.preschedule = preschedule, mc.set.seed = set.seed,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous> -> mclapply
Execution halted
```

Code:

```
dist<-array(0, dim=c(320,500,25))

mc<-8
cl<-makeCluster(mc)
registerDoMC(cl)
opts<-list(chunkSize=10)

for(a in 1:25) {
  dist[,,a]<-foreach(x=1:500, .combine='cbind', .options.mc=opts) %:% 
    foreach(y=1:320, .combine='c') %dopar% {
      gcd.slc(crdsx[y,x], crdsy[y,x], lot[a,5], lot[a,4])
    }
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

On a different machine, it works nicely with

```
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

instead of

```
registerDoMC(cl)
```

Comment: can you add sessionInfo() to the OP?

Comment: When you register a parallel backend with `registerDoMC`, the function `doMC` is set to execute when you call the function `%dopar%`. `doMC` includes a call to `mclapply`, so that's where it comes from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting that error because `registerDoMC` expects an integer argument, not a cluster object, while `registerDoParallel` expects either an integer or a cluster object.  Basically, you need to decide which package to use and not mix them.

If you use `doMC`, then you never create a cluster object.  A minimal `doMC` example looks like:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(3)
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% sqrt(i)
```

The `doParallel` package is a mashup of the `doMC` and `doSNOW` packages, and so you don't need to use cluster objects.  Converting the previous example to `doParallel` is very simple:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(3)
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% sqrt(i)
```

The confusing thing is that on Windows, `doParallel` will actually create and use a cluster object behind the scenes, while on Linux and Mac OS X, it doesn't use a cluster object because it uses `mclapply` just as in the `doMC` package.  I think that is convenient, but it can be a source of confusion.

Comment: Thank you. After modyfying numerous examples from various packages I was left with registerDoMc(cluster) in the middle of the night. Maybe would have never asked this question in the morning after a second sharp thought... Putting an integer as an argument and relying solely on doMC was indeed what I was looking for, thank you!